# How to get rid of spring boot's default exception?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I am new to spring boot and I am adding custom exceptions to my controller through controllerAdvisor.
In MyController.class, I am doing three operations

1. Get all the tickets present in the database.
2. Get ticket by id
3. Create the ticket.

Below mentioned class is MyController.class.

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private TicketServiceImpl ticketService;

    @GetMapping(/ticket)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllTickets() {

        List<Ticket> list=(List<Ticket>)ticketService.findAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(Constant.BASE_URL+"/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Ticket> getTicketById(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        Optional<Ticket> ticketData = Optional.ofNullable(ticketService.get(id));

         if(!ticketData.isPresent()){
             throw new RecordNotFoundException("id-" + id);
         }
           return new ResponseEntity<>(ticketData.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
       
    }

    @PostMapping(/ticket)
    public ResponseEntity<Ticket> createTicket(@RequestBody Ticket ticket) {
          
            ticketService.save(ticket);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(ticket, HttpStatus.CREATED);
     }

}
```

Below class is my custom exception handle class where I am handling my custom exceptions.

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked","rawtypes"})
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
        details.add(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse("Server Error", details);
        return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(RecordNotFoundException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleUserNotFoundException(RecordNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
        List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
        details.add(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse("Record Not Found", details);
        return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
        for(ObjectError error : ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors()) {
            details.add(error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse("Validation Failed", details);
        return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

The below class is specific for not found exceptions.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class RecordNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    public RecordNotFoundException(String exception) {
        super(exception);
    }
}
```

In application.properties, I am adding these three conditions

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
```

When I hit my server with GET API http://localhost:8080/ticke .It should throw bad request exception but its throwing Not found "404" exception and when I hit GET API http://localhost:8080/ticket/24, in this my id is not created. Hence, it should return resource not found exception.But, its returning, 500 internal server error.

Please advise on this.

Comment: What is value  of Constant.BASE_URL

Comment: @techiesantosh it's /ticket

Comment: `@GetMapping(/ticket)`  this will not compiled I think

Comment: So when your are hitting http://localhost:8080/ticke. Where **t** is missing at the end will always give you 404 as your controller is not aware of any mapping with **ticke**

Comment: @techisantosh as it is incomplete url, it should give me bad request exception

Comment: No. The request should go to valid url then only it will give BAD request exception. Plz refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because Spring was not able to find the endpoint you are looking for.  So it does not apply any controller advices to it, since it did not find a controller that maps to the requested URL.

[Here is a small article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-404-error) explaining it in a little more detail.